# Can't upload folder with large amount of files to google storage. I using "@ffmpeg-installer/ffmpeg" and @google-cloud/storage

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ffmpeg, google-cloud-storage

I upload file to google storage using "@ffmpeg-installer/ffmpeg" and @google-cloud/storage in my node.js App.
Step 1. file uploading to fs is in child processes - one process for each type of resolution (totaly six).
step 2. encription (converting to stream)
step 3. upload to google storage

I use "Upload a directory to a bucket" in order to send the video from the client to the Google Cloud Storage bucket.

This way is working fine only with small video.

for example when I upload video with duration one hour it split on chunk and totally I get more three thousands files. But the problem occurs when there are more than 1500 files

So actually i upload folder with large amount of files, but not all of this files are uploaded to cloud.

maybe someone had the similar problem and helps fix it.

```js
const uploadFolder = async (bucketName, directoryPath, socketInstance) => {
    try {
      let dirCtr = 1;
      let itemCtr = 0;
      const fileList = [];

      const onComplete = async () => {
        const folderName = nanoid(46);

        await Promise.all(
          fileList.map(filePath => {
            const fileName = path.relative(directoryPath, filePath);
            const destination = `${ folderName }/${ fileName }`;

            return storage
              .bucket(bucketName)
              .upload(filePath, { destination })
              .then(
                uploadResp => ({ fileName: destination, status: uploadResp[0] }),
                err => ({ fileName: destination, response: err })
              );
          })
        );

        if (socketInstance) socketInstance.emit('uploadProgress', {
          message: `Added files to Google bucket`,
          last: false,
          part: false
        });

        return folderName;
      };

      const getFiles = async directory => {
        const items = await fs.readdir(directory);
        dirCtr--;
        itemCtr += items.length;
        for(const item of items) {
          const fullPath = path.join(directory, item);
          const stat = await fs.stat(fullPath);
          itemCtr--;
          if (stat.isFile()) {
            fileList.push(fullPath);
          } else if (stat.isDirectory()) {
            dirCtr++;
            await getFiles(fullPath);
          }
        }
      }

      await getFiles(directoryPath);

      return onComplete();
    } catch (e) {
      log.error(e.message);
      throw new Error('Can\'t store folder.');
    }
  };
```

Comment: What's "huge"? What the size in memory? On which platform are you running your workload?

Comment: I have updated the description of the problem and hope it will be clearer. actually i upload folder with large amount of files, (the longer video the more files). I am working on Linux (Ubuntu) RAM 8GB